# How to run custom action when windows service changes its status to "Running" in TopShelf?

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I know TopShelf API has a method `AfterStartingService` which can be used to run some custom code after the service is starting, as its name implies. But this isn't helping me, because what I need is to be able to run an action after the Windows Service has actually started, that is, when its State changes to "Running".

Of course, it would also be useful if it allows us to wait for any other status besides "Running". I've searched on the internet and couldn't find any examples or documentation on how to do this. Also, I've tried in my own code, but couldn't make this work the way I need it.